# Sort dataset for grouped boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a rather untidy dataset and can't wrap my head around how to do this in R. Alternative would be to do this in Excel but since I have several of these, this would take forever.

So what I need is to create a **grouped boxplot**.
For this I think I need a dataset that consists of 4 columns: 
 **species, group (A or B), variable, value**. 
But what I have at the moment is only:
**variable and species_group (together in one column),**

Here is a reproducible example:

```
variable <- c('precipitation','soil','land use')
species1_A <- c(10000, 500, 1322)
species1_B <- c(11500, 200, 600)
species2_A <- c(10000, 500, 1489)
species2_B <- c(15687, 800, 587)
df <- data.frame(variable, species1_A, species1_B,species2_A, species2_B)
```

So I guess I have to create a whole new column "group" with A or B and somehow tell R to take that information from the "species1_A" name.

Can anyone help me please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(contains("species"), names_to = "name", values_to = "value") %>% 
  separate(name, c("species", "group"), "_") %>% 
  ggplot() +
  facet_wrap(~variable) +
  aes(x = species, y = value, color = group) +
  geom_point()
```

Sorry I'm not sure how you'd want things laid out and you only have one value per group in your example dataset. You can change `geom_point` to `geom_boxplot` once you have more variables per group. Spacing between the boxes can be adjusted with `position_dodge`. HTH.

Comment: Thank you so much!! That is almost it. Only problem now is that in the example dataset I wrote "species1_A" whereas in reality this is the name of the species. So I have multiple columns with different names (i.e. marmot_A, marmot_B, tiger_A, tiger_B, ...). So the "contains ("species")" thing in your code unfortunately will not work. 

The lack of values is just for the sake of the example. Dont worry.

Comment: Can replace contains(“species”) with contains(“_”). Would check https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/select_helpers.html for more info.